# Fetching ID3 metadata while HLS stream is being played on AppleTV via Airplay

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, id3, airplay

I am working on AVPlayer based streaming apps wherein I am relying on ID3 tags for reading metadata from the HLS stream. I am using KVO for this and observing AVPlayerItem’s `timedMetadata` property. This works perfectly well in  normal scenario. 
However when I route the playback to Apple TV via Airplay, I do not get any notifications for the said KVO. In fact, the timedMetadata property resets to `nil` once the Airplay is activated as the API doc says here,

```
“As an optimization for playback, AVPlayerItem may omit the processing of timed metadata when no observer of this property is registered. Therefore, when no such observer is registered, the value of the timedMetadata property may remain nil regardless of the contents of the underlying media.”
```

Is there any way, we can fetch `timedMetadata` property of `AVPlayerItem` while the steam is being played via Airplay mode.

Comment: Do you have any more information about this issue? Facing the same problem.

Comment: @DoubleT Unfortunately this is how it works I suppose. Apple TV take whole control of streaming while airplaying and there is no provision I found to fetch back those ID3 tags from the stream.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Was anyone able to find a solution? 